# How to write Bangla in Blender?

Tags: font

I was trying to write something in Blender in Bangla(Local Language in Bangladesh) but unable to write **bangla**.. Then I googled the problem and found that a similar post has been posted almost 7/8 years ago but it was about writing **arabic** but that technique didn't worked out for me. I also tried importing bangla font in Blender thinking it might help fix the issue but it didn't fixed the issue..

Is there anyone who knows how to write Bangla or if not is there any way I can tell the Blender Devs to fix this issue.. If you're Blender Dev and reading this post Please fix this issue.

Comment: If you have a Bangladesh font, I would think this would be very easy. How did you try to import it?

Comment: I used the text panel to import the fonts.

Comment: What was the resulting problem?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it's possible to use Bangla characters but, alas, not all of them. If you don't need যুক্ত বর্ণ। you add text go to edit mode and delete. Then you copy the text you want to use and paste it into the blender and, at the fonts tab, add a custom Bangla font. You will see it is working. You will see what you want to see...

Comment: For how long? How long people should do this boring thing? It only requires to update the text renderer is too big of deal..??